# Image colors look different on different browser

Tags: php, laravel, image

Hi i am facing an issue on my website when i upload image to my Laravel application the image colors looks different on different browsers.

Please help me to find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Hey man, check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749321/jpeg-color-renders-inconsistently-across-browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPEG color renders inconsistently across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749321/jpeg-color-renders-inconsistently-across-browsers)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with laravel or php. try drag and drop the image file in the browser, you will see that the problem still exist.

now, the color issue might be related with the ICC profile of the image.

If you have photoshop, open your image and do `save as` then uncheck the `Color profile` before saving.

Comment: Hi @N69S
I have done the same as you send and the result is this.
https://imgur.com/a/0ak6HC1

Comment: @WaseemBashir if you posted a lisk, it's not showing

Comment: Please check the link.

Comment: can you porvide me a link to the image in question?